# Sample estimate and Gaussian assumption

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, statistical-inference

I am confused with a certain issue. It would be very kind if someone to clarify.
Say I have data series $x_1,...x_n$ and i compute sample average as $avg =( x_1+...x_n)/n$. Does this imply I have assumed the data to be uniformly distributed ?
And similar assumption holds while computing sample standard deviation etc.

Comment: No, it doesn't imply any assumptions you've made about the data, but there's a question of what you plan on using the sample mean to do.